# Rails api active_storage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

Is there a way to create variants of images upon upload and store the variants rather than the entire image.

for example. a user uploads a picture that is 1000x1000, when I receive that upload in rails I want to create 3 variants,  a 100x100 a 300x300 and a 600x600 and store those in S3 then be able to retrieve them by doing something like `post.image.thumbnail`

It seems silly that everytime an image is request I must retrieve the full sized image from s3 and process it on the fly to serve it to the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for minimagick

add this to your gemfile

```
gem 'mini_magick'
```

and then you can use minimagick methods to transform the image

```
<%= image_tag user.avatar.variant(resize: "100x100") %>
```

[here is the documentation for this](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#transforming-images)

Comment: Im using minimagic, but it still uploads the original file and then processes it to resize when requested. I want to resize it before storing it on S3. so i can upload an image and in s3 i store perhaps a 100x100 thumb and a 600x600 image. so I dont have to process it everytime its requested.

Comment: You don't have to process it every time. If I am not wrong, the first time you ask for it, it creates the file and the second time, it just request the created before.

Comment: but doesnt that file expire? or is it just the url that expires?

Comment: it's just the url, you need to call processed before, to create the variant and upload to the service, then when you call it as above, it will just ask for the url. read here the documentation of variant to be more clear about it.
https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveStorage/Variant.html

Comment: mate, you have been an amazing help. Thank you so much!